# i can't figure out why this css is not working

Tags: css, html

*thirtydot edit: (there's no doctype)*

Here is the code in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/zwPTd8dd

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Layout</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #wholepage{
    background: #fff;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #header{
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto 0;
    }
   #header ul{
    border:1px solid #bbbbbb;
    width:100%;
    height:45px;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    list-style: none;
    }
    #header ul li{
    float: left;
    margin: 3px;
    }


    #login-form{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 750px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    border: 1px solid #4e4e4e;
    }

    #frontpage-content{
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 210px;
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;

    }


</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wholepage">
    <div id="header">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Profile</li>

            <li>username
            <input type="text"/>
            </li>
            <li>password
            <input type="password" />
            </li>
            <li><input type="submit" value="login"/>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="login-form">
    widget 1 : description of widget one here ... 
    </div>
    <div id="login-form">
    widget 2 : description of widget two here...
    </div>

    <div id="frontpage-content">
     content here<br/>
     content here<br/>
    </div>

    <p>Terms of use | Contact | About | Developers | Advertising | Services | Partners</p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's pushing down the "frontpage-content" div. I've been trying to fix this for a long time. I have no more ideas. :(

This problem is solved. Thank you Guys for helping.

Comment: A) what isn't working, exaclty, and b) you can show HTML here if you intent everything by 4 spaces, or highlight the code and click on the code button to do it for you.

Comment: Please be more specific, your question is vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming judging from how you've got the margins set that you want frontpage-content to be to the right of the login-form widgets?

If so, you're missing the CSS value for "[float](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_float.asp)".  I'd put all your sidebar content in a div with the id like "left-sidebar" and make it

```
#left-sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

#frontpage-content{
  position: relative;
  width: 750px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}

#login-form{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #4e4e4e;
}
```

And in your source after #frontpage-content, place:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

before your footer stuff.

Comment: ok, i tried and modified the div "login-form" to "right-sidebar" now if i put two "right-sidebar" div , its pushing the "frontpage-content" div to the right. How can i make the two div static in the width size. ?

Comment: No, don't replace login-form, enclose them in left-sidebar.  Editing my post to include more info.  I don't know what you mean by "static in the width size"

Comment: Edited - should do what you want it to now if you make those changes.

Comment: ok, i have enclosed "login-form" inside "right-sidebar" the "frontpage-content" div work good but the "right-sidebar" is becoming very small and its not pushing down the <p> tag. However, "frontpage-content" is pushing down the <p> tag.

Comment: Thanks so much @McAden its working now. You just solved which i've been trying for long time. Thank you for your help .

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/Mutant_Tractor/xNAaz/2/

Sure just add `position:fixed;` and `bottom:0;` to it's class.

Comment: Can you tell me how should i disable the last <p> paragraph contents from pushing up when the contents of the frontpage-content div increases. But the widget div remain same.

Comment: It is still pushing the widget content below. however the paragraph is not moving. Can you make it such that the "frontpage-content" div and "login-form" div does not change its size even if their contents is increased. Also, both the "frontpage-content" and "login-form" div pushes down the <p> paragraph instead of pushing up.

Comment: Thank you for your help Myles Gray. Code by McAden got it working. Really appreciate for your time today.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for...
http://jsfiddle.net/ZsjDL/2/

Floats can be tricky. Make sure you define width on floated elements and ids should not exist more than one time in your markup.

Comment: Thanks stanwilsonjr , your solution also works. Thank you for your time.